# Scroll to bookmark on same page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I made a Q&A page. I'd like to click on the question and have the page scroll to the question using jQuery.  What script do I use? Does anyone have an example I can learn from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest [LocalScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) which I've used in the past and found very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases (depends on how you "made" your Q&A page), you don't even need JQuery or any JavaScript.

Simply mark your answers with a name tag (for example `<A NAME="Answer11"/>` ) and then have every question be wrapped into a link to correct tag, e.g. `<LI><A HREF="#Answer11">Question  11</A>`.

Answer (score 0):

Really late at the party. Using bookmarks is the simplest solution (DVK's answer), but scrolling can be done in a more fancy way with `animate`:

```
$('html, body')
    .animate({
            // for fixed top div, you must substract its height from top
            scrollTop: $("#jumpBookmark").offset().top;
        },
        // animation duration
        500);
```